# Custom Query Builder Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Is it possible to create a custom query builder inside a model and return the query? Not a stressing issue but would be helpful.

```
/* Controller */

public function getOrders() 
{
   $orders = \App\Order::where('is_new', 1)->getFromUserStore();
}

/* Order Model */

public function getFromUserStore() 
{
  if(\Auth::user()->store->id == 1)
  {
      return $this->get();
  }
  else
  {
      return $this->where('status_id', 1)->get();
  }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: It's part of your question per se but I suggest you use the `use` operator for your namespace to avoid using the backslash all the time. For your controller, your should `use App\Order;` and for your model `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;`

Comment: @Wistar, I typically use `use`.. is there a performance issue with using the backslash? Thanks for the input.

Comment: I dont know about performance issue. Also, is the answer working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are looking for [Query Scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#query-scopes)

> Scopes allow you to define common sets of constraints that you may
>   easily re-use throughout your application.

```
/* Controller */  
public function getOrders() 
{
   $orders = \App\Order::where('is_new', 1)->getFromUserStore()->get();
}


/* Order Model */
public function scopeGetFromUserStore($query) 
{
  if(\Auth::user()->store->id == 1)
  {
      return $query;
  }
  else
  {
      return $query->where('status_id', 1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you.